# Project Euler Q22: Why do I get different results depending on when I remove the quotation marks?

Tags: ruby

How come if I run this:

```
get_score = proc{ |word, position|
  val = 0
  word[1..-2].each_byte do |c|
    val = val + (c.ord - 64)
  end
  name_score = val*(position+1)
}

puts File.read("names.txt").split(',').sort.map.with_index(&get_score).inject(:+)
```

I get the answer: 871193872

But if I run this:

```
get_score = proc{ |word, position|
  val = 0
  word.each_byte do |c|
    val = val + (c.ord - 64)
  end
  name_score = val*(position+1)
}

puts File.read("names.txt").gsub('"','').split(',').sort.map.with_index(&get_score).inject(:+)
```

I get this: 871190344

(The difference is that in the second one I used gsub to remove the quotation marks but in the first I kept them until I used word[1..-2] to only iterate through the characters in between the quotation marks)

And in this third version, it uses scan(/\w+/) which searches for whitespaces even though there are no whitespaces in the file, yet this is the one that gives the correct answer:

```
names = File.open('names.txt').read.scan(/\w+/).sort
puts names.map { |name|
        word_score = name.each_byte.map { |c| c - 64 }.reduce(:+)
        (names.index(name) + 1) * word_score
}.reduce(:+)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the sample data: http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt

Comment: [You need to show a short sample of your input data](http://sscce.org). As is, potential answerers have to chase down the sample data just to help you.

Comment: About the third one, `scan(/\w+/)` doesn’t look for “whitespaces”, but for runs of “word characters (letters, digits, underscores)”, which removes the commas and quotation marks from the computation, and gives the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you copy&pasted the input file or something like that instead of saving it. I tried your two codes and they work just fine:

```
$ ruby p22.rb
87119XX82
87119XX82
```

Now, if you asked how I'd write it (which you didn't :-)), let's keep the abstraction `get_score` but refactor things a little bit:

```
indexes = Hash[("A".."Z").map.with_index(1).to_a]
get_score = proc { |word, idx| indexes.values_at(*word.chars).reduce(:+) * idx }
sorted_names = File.read("names.txt").delete('"').split(',').sort
solution = sorted_names.map.with_index(1, &get_score).reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: I'd go with `delete('"')` or `tr('"', '')`. Either would probably be faster than `gsub('"', '')`.